# DRY Pagination for complex POST action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I implemented a stats panel in  my current project.
It's possible to select people by specific objects (**different Models**) which allows you for example to search for people which belong to in Group B, Organisation A and Flag A (**Group B ∩ Organisation A ∩ Flag A**; btw. it's possible to select multiple objects of the same class).

This makes my post-request very complex and has many parameters (sorting, fields, ...). The result is then displayed via jQuery in a special div.

What would be the best practice to make my project more flexible in order to support a page_id via the rails routes.

First I thought about hashing all the parameters in order to support absolute urls without form fields and then adding the page number (e.g. /stats_search/***param_hash***/2 ).

**Well, to be short:** I want a DRY and clean solution (without passing all my form fields again) in order to support multiple pages for a specific POST request (group selection) via GET requests.

Comment: Maybe you want to share some code, just help understand better your question, models, relations, expected result, what you already tried.

Comment: @iGian I think I found a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think caching the requests in a Hash and accessing the hash in a seperate GET request including the page and request id parameter should be ok.